# mongoDB references fetching takes time

Tags: mongodb, optimization, pymongo, mongoengine

I use mongoengine as Object-Document mapper. Here is a brief description of the collections that are causing the problem. Each document in collection A, can have a list of references to documents in Collection B.

```
class A(Document): 
    list_b = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(EB))
    #other fields are not mentioned.

class EB(EmbeddedDocument):
    b_reference = ReferenceField('B')
    loc = GeoPointField()

class B(Document):
    name = StringField()
    #other fields are not mentioned.
```

When i try to access the list objects of a particular document with

`document_of_A.list_b`

the execution time of the above line depends on the no.of references present in the list. For eg. it takes 100ms for 100 references in the list.

Is there a better way to fetch the references?, so that the execution time of the above mentioned line is reduced.

Comment: Welcome to the challenges of MongoDb document organization. :) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ Do you need all of the referenced documents?

Comment: Are the references to document `B` indexed such that a request for documents related to an `A` can be returned all at once?

Comment: no, there is no index on the 'list_b' field.

Comment: If they're not indexed, MongoDB is going to need to search every document potentially for a match.

Comment: no change even after i created the index.

Comment: You need to see what query is being sent. And/or what indexes are being used via `explain`: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.11/tutorial.html

Comment: The query returns the documents of collection A. Query time is not the problem, but when i loop over each document and try to get the list of references it takes significant time. I do not understand this part where the time is consumed to just access the list_b.

Comment: If it's needing to make individual queries for each secondary document, then it's likely going to be slow unless you can retrieve them all at once (find all where B owned by A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `select_related` flag when querying if you want to get all the references quickly.  Please note reference lookups will cost extra queries and `select_related()` is designed to reduce the number of round trips to mongodb.

```
# Single document lookup
document_of_A.select_related(2)

# Queryset
A.objects.select_related(2)
```

Why 2 for the select_related lookup? Well the recursive depth is:

1. look up any references in the list itself
2. looking up references in the individual embedded documents

Comment: when i use select_related(2) as part of query, the query time is the same, but the optimization is not achieved when i try to get the references. Where as, when i use select_related(2) as part of single document, references time is saved, but now the select_related(2) part takes time.

Comment: Ah maybe for the query it should be select_related(3) sorry.  The number is the depth it should go down.

Comment: my bad, the test that i did earlier was wrong. select_related(2) worked now.

Comment: @Ross how to convert select_related() result to_json()?